# Ansible install updates from SCCM

Tags: ansible

I deployed Ansible 2.9.6 and created a playbook:

```
---
- name: Install update
  hosts: scom_servers

  tasks:
   - name: install windows update
     win_updates:
        state: installed
        server_selection: managed_server
        register: update_result
        reboot: yes
        reboot_timeout: 1200
        log_path: c:\ansible.txt
```

When I run the playbook I don't have changes on my servers. Hosts scom_servers contains three Windows 2019 servers with an sccm client.  Updates deploy from sccm but don't install.

Comment: Run it with `state: searched` and check the `category_names`. IIRC they have changed the spelling end the default categories don't exist anymore.

Comment: Don't work. I change playbook 


---
- name: Install update
  hosts: scom_servers

  tasks:
   - name: install windows update
     win_updates:
        state: searched
        category_names:
         - SecurityUpdates
         - CriticalUpdates
         - UpdateRollups
         - Updates
        server_selection: managed_server
        reboot: yes
        reboot_timeout: 1200
        log_path: c:\ansible.txt
     register: update_result

   - name: Reboot host if required
     win_reboot:
     when: update_result.reboot_required

Comment: I think it's don't work, because sccm handles the updates using wsus but not using regular update mechanisms. Everytime i get 0 updates

Comment: To use the `state: searched` you need output the variable `update_result` in another task using the [`debug` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html). Then you can see the category names that currently have updates.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for an answer on how to do windows updates via SCCM & Ansible I found this sort of unanswered article. This is not supported, according to github and the Ansible documentation for win_updates module: https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.windows/issues/194

Just thought I leave it here to round it up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/529188)

Answer (score 0):

The "win_update" Ansible module does not support SCCM installation as it is not supported by its PowerShell core.

However, there's a [batteries-included PowerShell script](https://timmyit.com/2016/08/01/sccm-and-powershell-force-install-of-software-updates-thats-available-on-client-through-wmi/) that could be turned into Ansible module with minimal hassle.